# Django ajax file upload to request.FILES

Tags: django, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm using [Valumns File Uploader](http://github.com/valums/file-uploader) to load files to django. This supports an ajax upload via `XHR` for modern browsers and an iFrame fallback for older ones like IE.

Now the problem: If I upload large files, only iFrame upload works, because here the files are mapped into `request.FILES` and django writes them to the disk immediately instead of memory.

If `XHR` upload is used, I have to read request._raw_post_data and write this to disk, but it fails with an `MemoryError`.

This is my file uploader initialization:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    'action': uploadUrl,
    'multiple': true,
    'allowedExtensions': allowedExtensions,
    'element': selector,

    'debug': true,

    'onComplete': completeFunction,
    'onProgress': progressFunction,
    'onSubmit': submitFunction
});
```

At the django end I use the following code to write the file content to disk:

```
# open a new file to write the contents into
new_file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
destination = open(upload_path + new_file_name, 'wb+')

# differentiate between xhr (Chrome, FF) and pseudo form uploads (IE)
if len(request.FILES) > 0: # IE
    for chunk in request.FILES[0].chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)

else: # others
    destination.write(request._raw_post_data)
destination.close()
```

I also tried [this solution from Alex Kuhl](http://kuhlit.blogspot.de/2010/12/ajax-uploads-in-django-with-little-help.html), but this fails with an `IOError: request data read error`.

Is there any way to get the files uploaded via `XHR` into `request.FILES` and so use the django builtin handling?

Comment: What part of that solution did you try? If you do `request._raw_post_data.read(1024)` like he does and write it out 1024 bytes at a time, you shouldn't have any memory errors.

Comment: The one you mentioned. It turned out, that using another file all works fine, so it seems that the first file was corrupt.

Comment: Okay it has nothing to do with the file. Chrome works fine, Firefox not.

Comment: @Penthi did you ever resolve this issue? I'm stuck with it as well.

Comment: Forget the deleted comment, this is not related to firebug. At the moment, I don't have an answer to this.